# Making a pseudo-element to fully cover the parent container?

Tags: html, css

I have created a `div` with an `img` and some text inside. I want that the `:before` pseudo-element to fully cover the parent `div`, but I don't know how to do that.

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/2y6uh3j6/1/)

```css
.container {
    display:inline-block;
    width:33%;
    padding:15px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:2px solid blue;
}
.container:before {
    content:"";
    background-color:green;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    transition:all 0.3s ease 0s;
    z-index:2;
}
.container img {
    max-width:100%;
}
.container h2 {
    font-size:1.5em;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:400;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm unclear; what do you want to happen that isn't happening in your demo code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the following.

- Add `position: relative;` to `.container`
- Then add these lines to `.container:before`:

  ```
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a good first post, I'd still like to recommend you read [answer]. This page will explain the best practices which will increase your chances of having your answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s my answer:

https://jsfiddle.net/2y6uh3j6/4/

Key insights:

1. You need to establish a **positioning context** in the parent container. This is achieved by setting `position: relative` on `.container`
2. The padding problem can be side-stepped by using `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;` (letting you drop `height` and `width`).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add positioning to the parent element and :before element. Though I'm unsure what you intent to do with the red overlay.

http://jsfiddle.net/basyqLv8/

```
.container {
    position:relative;

.container:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
```